# Histograms for multiple categorical variables

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataframe similar to the following:

```
Ethnicity  Tissue  Volume
---------  ------  ------
Asian        A      1.2
Asian        A      2.6
Asian        B      0.7
Asian        B      0.8
Black        A      1.1
Black        A      1.0
Black        B      0.9
Black        B      0.6
White        A      1.8
White        A      2.0
White        B      0.4
White        B      0.6
```

I would like to make a histogram showing frequencies of volumes per ethnicity per tissue, but I'm getting a little stuck on how to do this with multiple categorical variables.

What is the best way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a `Combined` column,
with values such as `Asian-A`, `Asian-B`.

Then you're back to a simpler problem that you know how to solve.